# Filter Django ResourceRelatedField's queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jsonapi-serialize

In our project we are using ResourceRelatedField for a foreign key field in one of our serializers to comply with JSON:API format. This is how it looks:

```
    types = ResourceRelatedField(
        queryset=Type.objects,
        many=True
    )
```

The problem that I have is that I want to exclude some of the items from the queryset of this field so that I don't get all the items from the `Type` model, but a subset.

If I write something like this it doesn't work:

```
    types = ResourceRelatedField(
        queryset=Type.objects.exclude(id=13),
        many=True
    )
```

Didn't find anything related in the [documentation](https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#resourcerelatedfield).

Comment: Hi, I was running into a similar issue. 
Would you share your working solution?

I was trying the solution of Aprimus but ran into this error:

 "AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`."

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, I do not remember any more, we refactored the code thousand times after that :) Sorry man..

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps You can use a SerializerMethodResourceRelatedField? (not tested).

```
types = SerializerMethodResourceRelatedField(many=True)

def get_types(self, obj):
    return  Type.objects.exclude(id=13)
```